Maven Build Failure: "Zip END header not found" during Apache Atlas 2.3.0 Installation on Oracle Linux 9.4
I'm trying to install Apache Atlas 2.3.0 on Oracle Linux 9.4 and encountered a build failure during the Maven compilation process. The error appears to be related to the org.restlet dependencies. Here are the key parts of the error log:
[ERROR] error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet/2.4.3/org.restlet-2.4.3.jar; zip END header not found
[ERROR] error reading /root/.m2/repository/org/restlet/jee/org.restlet.ext.servlet/2.4.3/org.restlet.ext.servlet-2.4.3.jar; zip END header not found
[ERROR] /root/apache-atlas-sources-2.3.0/test-tools/src/main/java/org/apache/atlas/runner/LocalSolrRunner.java:[15,1] cannot access org.apache.atlas.runner
[ERROR]   ZipException opening "org.restlet-2.4.3.jar": zip END header not found

I've already tried the following steps:

Cleared the local Maven cache by deleting the .m2/repository folder.
Re-downloaded the org.restlet dependencies using mvn clean install.
Despite these actions, the issue persists. The restlet JAR files seem to be corrupted or incomplete.

Environment:
Apache Atlas 2.3.0
Oracle Linux 9.4
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (I also tried with Maven 3.9.9)
Any advice on how to resolve this issue or suggestions for further troubleshooting would be appreciated!

First change the checksum policy in your settings.xml to fail https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#repositories and read this
https://blog.soebes.io/posts/2018/10/2018-10-13-maven-artifact-checksums-what/
Furthermore keep on  Maven 3.9.9 and rerun your build with mvn -U ......

Thanks khmarbaise for the suggestion! I updated the checksum policy in my settings.xml as suggested and kept Maven at version 3.9.9. However, I'm still encountering the same error

Have you declared the Restlet Maven repository in your POM as explained here?
https://restlet.talend.com/downloads/current/
Note that starting with version 2.5 RC1, Restlet is now published directly in Maven Central.
